# how to reesolve react table setstate problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, http-status-code-304

when i get data from mongoose using node expressjs it get data in postman but not get in my react app and node shows 304 error i cannot figure out error
[image][![this is react app error][image: 304 error in nodejs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6XCC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6XCC.png)

please resolve this problem to setstate my data in react app

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i get error in node when i connect to it react that not set state in react page